# Need to Check the Combination of List2 and List3 in List 1. For Example:- [125, 600] **exists in** [[160, 600], [125, 600],[120,600]]

Tags: java, collections

I have Three list

- List 1 `[[[160, 600], [125, 600],[120,600]], [[1003, 70], [1000, 60]], [[1003,90], [970,90],[728, 90]],[[300,250],[300,600],[300,292],[300,600]],[300, 100], [300, 250], [300, 250], [300, 250], [[728, 90], [1003, 90]], [1, 1]]`
- List 2 `[125, 1000px, 1003, 300px, 300px, 300, 300, 300, 728]`
- List 3 `[600, 50px, 80, 600px, 100px, 250, 250, 250, 90]`

My Requirement is, I have to check the Combination of List2 & List3 exists in List 1 or not.

**For Example:-**
[125, 600]  **exists in**  [[160, 600], [125, 600],[120,600]]

I am looking for the best possible approach here.

Comment: You need [edit] your question to explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve here, because otherwise a simple `System.out.println(`"[20, 10] [33, 22]")` is the simplest solution to your issue. Why would you expect the output you give when none of the lists you have contain 20 and 10 in that order and why do you add both to the list 3 times when you only want stuff to be output once? None of that code makes much sense without an explanation of *what* you are trying to do and *why*.

Comment: So you don't want duplicates? Then you should just use a `Set`, like `Set<List<Integer>>`

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand why you need a loop here. It doesn't make sense, because you are overwriting your values when you use:

```
arrlist.add(count,one);
arrlist.add(count,two);
```

count has the same value in these lines.

Try this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> one = new ArrayList<>();
one.add(10);
one.add(22);
ArrayList<Integer> two = new ArrayList<>();
two.add(20);
two.add(33);
arrlist.add(0,one);
arrlist.add(1,two);
System.out.println(arrlist);
```

And the output will be: [[10, 22], [20, 33]]

Edit: But i am still not sure if this is what you want.